# Show all bookmarks using javascript

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

I'm trying to list all of my bookmarks using Javascript. Is there any way that I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The bookmarks list is NOT available to javascript, as it would represent a security hole/privacy leak. At most you can use javascript to add a link to the list, but not retrieve anything already there.

Answer (score 2):

In web design, there are some limitations due to security. Such as this, javascript would have to read your web folder on your computer and display the information from your computer. That would be bad security wise.

Use social bookmarking, and update it when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to show your bookmarks is though xul aka an extension if this is what you want then look up places api. Places is a sqlite database located n ur profile folder.It's name is places.sqlite

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox, there is a file called bookmarks.html in the profile folder. You can open this file and insert some JavaScript.

But as mentioned before, you can't (for good reasons) not access the bookmarks directly using JavaScript from any page.